# Не совсем понимаю, что требуется

Tags: java

**Задача**:
Реализуйте метод, возвращающий ответ на вопрос: правда ли, что a + b = c ?
Допустимая погрешность – 0.0001 (1E-4)
Можно использовать класс Math и его методы. Класс Math доступен всегда, импортировать его не надо.
В качестве примера написано заведомо неправильное выражение. Исправьте его.

**Требования**:
Метод должен иметь сигнатуру: doubleExpression(double a, double b, double c)**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**

**Изначальный код**:

```
public static boolean doubleExpression(double a, double b, double c) {
}
```

**Мой код**:

```
public class Java {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public static boolean doubleExpression(double a, double b, double c) {
            doubleExpression = Math.abs(a-b)<(1E-4);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Вопрос**: В правильном ли я направлении двигаюсь, либо может дадите какие-то советы, подсказки, **но не решение**, задача пока что не проходит условия.

Comment: "В правильном ли я направлении двигаюсь" - как можно двигаться в правильном направлении, если код не компилируется?

Comment: поэтому я и задал здесь вопрос

Comment: Хорошо. Ответ: в неправильном направлении.

Comment: а если не трудно, подскажите, что вообще не так делаю или абсолютно все в этом коде неправильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean doubleExpression(double a, double b, double c) {
  return Math.abs(a + b - c) <= 0.0001;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

вы в методе  `doubleExpression = Math.abs(a-b)<(1E-4);` от а отминание b и сравниваете с погрешностью. и вне зависисти от результата вычисления возвращаете true    `return true;`
если без ответа, а с подсказками, то мне видится несколько вариантов

1. тернарный оператор
   `return (условие) ? true : false;`
2. if ( условие ) return true;

   ```
    else return false;
   ```

Comment: `условие` - уже булевское значение. Зачем нужны дополнительные `true` и `false`?